# EdmGen.exe won't work with a System.Data.SQLite version greater than 1.0.94.0

Tags: xml, entity-framework, .net-4.0, system.data.sqlite

I've been trying to set up entity framework with System.Data.SQLite (targeting .NET 4.0).  I'm using Visual Studio 2017, so I know there are no design time components available.

I happened upon this guide for manually setting everything up: https://liiw.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/sqlite-entity-framework-database-first.html

I will however summarise what I've got from following the instructions in the link above:

A single folder, containing the following items:

- `EdmGen.exe` (copied from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`)
- `EdmGen.exe.config`
- `x86` and `x64` folders, each containing their own respective `SQLite.Interop.dll`
- `System.Data.SQLite.dll`
- `System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll`
- `System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll`
- `TestDatabase.sqlite`, which contains some test tables.
- `gen.bat`

The content of `EdmGen.exe.config` is as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
                 description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
                 type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

The content of `gen.bat` is as follows:

```
EdmGen.exe /mode:fullgeneration /c:"Data Source=TestDatabase.sqlite" /provider:System.Data.SQLite /entitycontainer:TestDatabase /project:TestDatabase /language:CSharp
```

Running `gen.bat` (or the command above) with the `System.Data.SQLite` binaries being the latest version of System.Data.SQLite (or any version greater than 1.0.94.0) produces the following error:

```
error 7001: The provider returned schema mapping information that is not valid.
        Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
StoreSchemaDefinition(2,65) : error 0175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.
```

It works with version 1.0.94.0 of the System.Data.SQLite assemblies.

Googling the errors has not turned up any answers as to the problem I am experiencing.  What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went and opened [a ticket on system.data.sqlite.org](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/d6e1fdba1e2b1f5ce470aa7386f129fa6df442e6) and it turns out that `EdmGen.exe` does not support Entity Framework 6.  They provided the following instructions which worked for generating the objects:

> The EdmGen tool is apparently not compatible with EF6.  Instead, you will want
>   to use the legacy provider, which is System.Data.SQLite.Linq.
>
> In the "EdmGen.exe.config" file, use:
>
> ```
> <configuration>
>     <system.data>
>         <DbProviderFactories>
>             <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
>             <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
>             <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" />
>             <add name="SQLite Data Provider (LINQ)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (LINQ)" type="System.Data.SQLite.Linq.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.Linq" />
>         </DbProviderFactories>
>     </system.data>
>     <system.diagnostics>
>       <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
>         <listeners>
>           <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
>            <remove name="Default" />
>          </listeners>
>        </trace>
>      </system.diagnostics>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> And then in the "gen.bat" file:
>
> ```
> EdmGen.exe /mode:fullgeneration /c:"Data Source=TestDatabase.sqlite" /provider:System.Data.SQLite.Linq /entitycontainer:TestDatabase /project:TestDatabase /language:CSharp
> ```
>
> The "EdmGen.exe.config" file above will also generate a trace log file
>   in the current directory, which may be useful in debugging.  You can
>   remove that section if you like.

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any way to generate the objects for Entity Framework 6, and I'm fairly new to Entity Framework in general so don't really have much knowledge on the difference between Entity Framework 6 and the previous versions of Entity Framework.  Still, hopefully this answer will be of use to anyone else encountering this issue in the future.